# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate method not called

Tags: ios, uikit

I implemented this method on the controller to present:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return [[MyAnimationController alloc] init];
}
```

Here are my initWithCoder: method on that view controller:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.transitioningDelegate = self;
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
    }
    return self;
}
```

MyAnimationController.m:

```
@implementation MyAnimationController

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    NSLog(@"Start Transition");
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}

@end
```

I never received the NSLog and the UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate method was not called either. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: How do you present your controller? In which file do you implement the initWithCoder: method?

Comment: I'm using storyboard segue to present the view controller and initWithCoder is in the segue's destination view controller.

Comment: I think default storyboard segue overrides what you have done in code. What are the segue properties in IB? Have you tried presenting your controller with `-presentViewController: animated: completion:` ?

Comment: I did -presentViewController:animated:completion: it has no effect.

Comment: Also, my sue is a modal segue.